# How to know the total amount of RAM of a computer?

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to have basic stats about the computer running my app, in order to adjust several things depending of that result. Is there a  way to know that info? is there a npm package I can use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With Node.js [OS](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html) package you can do this and much more.

Take a look in [os.freemem](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_freemem) or [os.totalmem](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_totalmem)

From Node.js documentation:

> os.freemem()
>
> ## Returns the amount of free system memory in bytes.

> os.totalmem()
>
> ## Returns the total amount of system memory in bytes.

Answer (score 1):

index.ts

```
import os from 'os';

console.log('RAM: ', os.totalmem());
console.log('Free RAM: ', os.freemem());
```

output -

```
RAM:  8496254976
Free RAM:  1699966976
```